# Meteor not updating sub document is not working

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Hi every one can some please let me know why I can not update my sub-document. I can update the normal document fields but not the sub document I have the method hard coded here just to try get it to work.

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';
import './Months.js';

export const Product = new Mongo.Collection('product');

ProductItem = new SimpleSchema({    
    author: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
            return this.userId
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    fileId: {
        type: String,
        autoValue: function() {
            return this._id
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    },
    name: {
        type: String
    },
    sellingPrice: {
        type: Months,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
    },
    purchasePrice: {
        type: Months,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
    }
});

Product.allow({
    insert: function (userId, doc) {
        // the user must be logged in, and the document must be owned by the user
        return !!userId;
    },
    update: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only change your own documents
        return !!userId;
    },
    remove: function (userId, doc) {
        // can only remove your own documents
        return doc.owner === userId;
    },
    fetch: ['owner']
});


Meteor.methods({
    updateProduct: function(id, newVal, target, inner) {
        console.log(id + "" + target);
        Product.update(id, {
            $set: {'sellingPrice.$.M1': 10 },
        });
    },
});



Product.attachSchema( ProductItem );
```

I also tried

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateProduct: function(id, newVal, target, inner) {
        console.log(id + "" + target);
        Product.update(id, {
            $set: {'sellingPrice.$': {'M1': 10} },
        });
    },
});
```

And also

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateProduct: function(id, newVal, target, inner) {
        console.log(id + "" + target);
        Product.update(id, {
            $set: {'sellingPrice.M1': 10 },
        });
    },
});
```

and still noting , nada.

**Months**

import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import { check } from 'meteor/check';

```
Months = new SimpleSchema({
    M0: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
    },
    M1: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        },
    },
    M2: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M3: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M4: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M5: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M6: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M7: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M8: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M9: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M10: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },
    M11: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function() {
            return 0;
        },
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }

    },

});
```

So any help would be great thanks

Comment: Can you please add the Months.js schema?

Comment: Hey @andresk thanks for the reply there you go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I saw on [autoValue docs](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#autovalue), I believe that you won't be able to update a month because you are using:

```
autoValue: function() {
        return 0;
}
```

on the schema. And this always changes the value to 0 when updating.

So you could try removing it and see if it works.

If you want a default value, you can use [defaultValue](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#defaultvalue)

Answer (score 0):

When you say that your data type for sellingPrice is `Months`, you are saying that you will store an ID of an other object of type Months.

If you have stored your months in other collection, you will have to somehow get the ID of the month. But if you don't need to store the months, you can declare a Month as an object with properties. https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#schema-keys.

Also, you can use Autoform and declare the schema of the month, and using quickForm you will have insert and edit operations out-of-the box.

Comment: Hey thanks a million sounds great when you say I can use Autoform and declare the schema , what do you mean

Comment: That you just need to create the schema `Months = new SimpleSchema({` in the same file you create the collection `ProductItem`; in that way, Autoform will render the fields of the Months schema, but with no need to declare a collection of Months.